# Why can I not select a one-to-one relationship?

Tags: powerbi

My report is accessing two MySQL tables of sports matches from two different sources. Let's call them `big_table` and `little_table`. Where possible I've matched all the `little_table` matches to the big table and recorded the `little_table` IDs in a column in `big_table` that's joined with a foreign key relationship and enforced with a unique index.

I want to create a one-to-one relationship between the two tables to enable a one-to-many join I need to do from `little_table` to another table. However, I keep being my chosen cardinality isn't valid.

I'm absolutely positive there are no duplicates in the `little_table_id` column - MySQL wouldn't allow it. I understand from reading around `Null` values are treated as unique so they shouldn't be causing a problem. I've also checked the datatypes of the columns and they're `123` which I assume means integer and therefore can't contain blanks.

I can't think of anything else that could be going wrong but clearly something is! Any ideas?

Comment: Do your big table also contain single id? or duplicates are there?

Comment: Hi. Both tables have a primary key with the big table having a `little_table_id` column which has a unique index applied to it.

Comment: can you show some sample data from both table?

Comment: @mkRabbani - sure. What's the best format to do this?